# routes.rb file edited but not updated in passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am using passenger with NGINX to deploy my rails application. Once it worked I wanted to play a bit with the routes file to see how easy it is to deploy an application update. I changed the routes.rb file and ran the two following commands:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
passenger-config restart-app $(pwd)
```

When I try to access my rails app now, it still works, but its behaviour is the one expected from the old routes.rb file.

Am I missing a command?

Edit:

What I am trying to change in the route file is the subdomain constraint.

this is what it looked without the constraint:

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :accounts
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/'  do
      scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
        resources :accounts, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
        resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
      end
  end
end
```

This is what it looks once I put the subdomain constraints:

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :accounts
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
      scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
        resources :accounts, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
        resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
      end
  end
end
```

Once I have updated the file from the first version to the second one shown, The show, create, update and destroy actions still work without the api subdomain.

Comment: Could you please share your routes file and any one example

Comment: I have edited my post. @Yas